# AngularJS/JavaScript Remove specific element from Localstorage array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array in my LocalStorage that I manipulate with ngStorage.
I am trying to remove items from there but when I use

```
$localStorage.someArrayName.splice(id, 1);
```

only the first removed item works fine, then removing stop working as I would like to.

I also tried something like this:

```
        if (id === $localStorage.someArrayName.length) {
            $localStorage.someArrayName.pop();
        }

        else if (id === 0) {
            $localStorage.someArrayName.shift();
        }

        else {
            $localStorage.someArrayName.splice(id, 1);
        }
```

But I get even more buggy result

I tried from the example in https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage like this:

```
delete $localStorage.someArrayName[id];
```

but it deletes the values and I get null,null,null values in my local storage array. And then I even get ng repeat error about duplicate values:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed...

I cannot handle it. I am not sure if it's some small issue or I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Can you give me some guidance? Thank you in advance!

This is how my array looks like saved in the localstorage:

```
[{"content":"something"},{"content":"else"}] //etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are using ng-repeat for something and your ids are there. If you use **$index** as value for your **id** parameter when you remove at item from the array, your array numbering is not longer the same and the **id** is not what you expect to be.

You also do not need the pop() and shift() methods.

Asuming your ng-repeat is something like this:

```
<element ng-repeat="item in someThing">
    {{item.prop}} <childelem ng-click=delete($index)>delete</childelem>
</element>
```

and if your function is:

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {

    $localStorage.someArrayName.splice(id, 1);

};
```

Then you would need something like this:

```
<element ng-repeat="item in someThing">
    {{item.prop}} <childelem ng-click=delete(item)>delete item</childelem>
</element>
```

and:

```
$scope.delete = function (item) {

   $localStorage.someArrayName.splice($localStorage.someArrayName.indexOf(item), 1);

};
```

and this is going to remove the entire `{"content":"something"}`
from your array.

No idea if this is the right direction of the problem and if this is the scenario, but I hope it will help you. Best regards!

Comment: Thank you! It is working this way! I can't explain it to myself yet on 100% but :))